# Как исправить ошибку Undefined variable?

Tags: php, laravel

Ошибка: `Undefined variable: user`
Как мне это красиво исправит ? Я могу присвоить `$user` присвоить какое-то значение дефолтное, но это наверное не красиво будет. Может есть еще какие-то варианты ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: так ошибка  ниже, когда я передаю во view не сущ переменную.

Comment: емае, красивее будет в `if` сделать `} else { $user = array(); }`

Comment: на самом деле, в данном случае, присвоить `$user` стартовое значение - не будет являться плохим вариантом.

Comment: @entithat -.- потому что логика будет нарушена.

Comment: @entithat я заметил, видел бы не написал. если внести `return` в `if`, то если `Auth::check` - даст `TRUE`, то все нормально. НО если даст `FALSE`, то у тебя функция ничего не вернет, потому что `return` в `if`е, а дублировать 2 раза `return view...` - плохо, ибо дубликат кода.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Перед if поставьте хотя-бы $user=null, так как если пользователь не авторизован она у вас не будет обЪявленна